# app.config file C# winforms preserve the connection string

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an `app.config` file in Winforms application that holds a connection string.  This is to go out to multiple tenant (clients) as a separate file.  These clients have different database sources. This config file also holds other version information such as EF, Telerik reporting etc...

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
```

and

```
<section name="Telerik.Reporting"  
         type="Telerik.Reporting.Configuration.ReportingConfigurationSection, Telerik.Reporting, Version=8.1.14.804, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" 
         allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
```

The problem I have is when we have an updated version of EF or Telerik reporting with our application and we deploy (auto-deploy) this we need to overwrite the `app.config` file in the client directory to update the versions in the client config file. They then lose their connection setting and I do not want the client to have to go and re-enter it.

My question:

Is there a best practice to overcome this issue? Should I hold the connection string somewhere else?

Comment: You can move your connection string to registry, independent of your application's binaries/files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an external configuration file that is referenced from the application config file. E.g. include this section in your config file.

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
</configuration>
```

The external config file is described http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that storing connection settings in plaintext on a workstation is still a bad idea.

Using Windows registry for stuff like this is a definite no-no these days.

Comment: Thanks for all responses. This has been implemented successfully

Answer (score 4):

Yep, the best thing to do is to move your connection strings section to an another config file and reference that file within your app.config.

For example create a new file called connectionStrings.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Default" connectionString="[client_connection_string] "/>  
</connectionStrings>
```

And in your app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config" />  
</configuration>
```

A full example can be found [here](http://www.davidgiard.com/2012/05/25/MovingConfigSectionsToExternalFiles.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you can try to hold all connection data that you need in separate xml file so it dont get overwrite when you preform a deploy of updated version.